# Construtor sem parametros não esta funcionando, está deixando o objeto como null

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe com dois construtores. O construtor vazio (sem argumentos) não está funcionando.
O programa não apresenta erro. Um dos construtores recebe os parâmetros `nome` e `limitedecredito`; e outro, vazio, inicializa o `CPF`.

Acontece que o campo `cpf` (TCPF) tá ficando com o valor `NULL`.

Construtor da classe cliente:

```
public Cliente():base()
{ 
}
```

**Programa Principal:**

```
(...)
case 1:
    Console.Clear();
    c1 = new Cliente();
    Console.Write("CPF:");
    CPF = Console.ReadLine();
    if (c1.setCPF(CPF) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CPF inválido");
        Console.ReadKey();
        break;
    }
    Console.Write("Nome:");
    string nome = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Limite de credito R$:");
    double limitecredito = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    c1 = new Cliente(nome, limitecredito);
    LC.Add(c1);
    Console.Write("Cadastro realizado com sucesso");
    Console.ReadKey();
    break;
(...)
```

**Classe `Cliente`:**

```
private double limitecredito;

public Cliente():base()
{ 
}

public Cliente(string n, double limitec) : base(n)
{
    limitecredito = limitec;
}
```

**Classe `Pessoa` (Mãe):**

```
private string nome;
private TCPF cpf;

public Pessoa()
{
    cpf = new TCPF();
}

public Pessoa(string n)
{
    cpf = new TCPF();
    nome = n;
}

public string Nome
{
    get { return nome; }
}

public bool setCPF(string X)
{
    return cpf.ValidaCpf(X);
}

public string Cpf
{
    get { return cpf.Cpf; }
}
```

Comment: Onde está o erro?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/U84zk8 veja isso, e qual o erro ?

Comment: O programa tá sem erro algum acontece que eu criei dois construtores um para armazenar os atributos nome e limitedecredito e um para iniciar o CPF acontece que o CPF(objeto) tá ficando com o valor NULL

Answer (score 1):

Se com um fluxo tão simples foi possível chegar a esse uma complexidade deste tamanho, o destino desse programa certamente vai ser o descarte.

Um problema é bastante trivial, mas o caminho que você escolheu percorrer é penoso de verdade.

Sobre a sua pergunta e o código que você postou, há várias coisas acontecendo, menos o que o título dela sugere:

1. Num primeiro momento você instancia um cliente (`c1 = new Cliente();`), recebe o cpf e o nome, mas depois que o usuário informa o limite de crédito você substitui a instância anterior do cliente (`c1 = new Cliente(nome, limitecredito);`);
2. O seu método `setCpf` não *seta* o cpf. Ele valida. E se o `ValidarCpf` *seta* ele não sabe quem é ele mesmo nesse jogo de cartas;
3. Seu `cpf`(`TCPF`) não está nulo. Ele tem uma instância, mas suas propriedades provavelmente não estão inicializadas (não tivemos acesso à classe TCPF para confirmar);

Concluindo, os construtores estão funcionando certinho, mas você está fazendo uma tremenda bagunça na lógica de programação e na utilização dos conceitos de OO.
[Nesse exemplo de implementação do seu código](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kLWbxK), você pode ver que a instância está 'viva', mas o valor do CPF em si está nulo.

Esse mesmo programa, (considerando a sua linha de modelagem e programação) [poderia ser feito de maneira um pouco mais simples e com menos reescrita](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Sou9a).

Espero ter ajudado.